# Use iBeacon to load UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, ibeacon

Hello: I am an iOS development student. I am working on my final project in advanced iOS. I basically want to make an app that loads a web page within the app when the user comes close to an iBeacon. I did some research and found a sample of code that changes the background color when it comes into the range of my iBeacon. I tested it and it does work. Here is the code I am working with. I am sorry, but I am a newbie. I think if I change the last line and the UIColor elements I can get this to work. Can someone help? Basically I want it to load google.com as a UIWebview when I get close to a iBeacon. The code is in swift.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "307CCCA5-7AE8-4EDF-986C-DD93F48C3105"), identifier: "basso")
let colors = [
    12345: UIColor(red: 84/255, green: 77/255, blue: 160/255, alpha: 1),
    99999: UIColor(red: 142/255, green: 212/255, blue: 220/255, alpha: 1),
    11111: UIColor(red: 162/255, green: 213/255, blue: 181/255, alpha: 1)
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    locationManager.delegate = self
    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!, inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {
    let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.Unknown }
    if (knownBeacons.count > 0) {
        let closestBeacon = knownBeacons[0] as CLBeacon
        self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[closestBeacon.minor.integerValue]
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You haven't explained what it does wrong currently

Comment: Are you asking how to load a `UIWebView`? If so I'd suggest you show what you've tried and where you are running into problems. A simple google search will give plenty of tutorials on using `UIWebView`s

Comment: Yes I am basically asking how to get it to load a UIWebview NOT change the background color. When my iPhone comes into proximity it loads UIWebView. I know how to make a UIWebView I just dont know how to trigger the load. I am a second year mobile app student and I am very new to this.

Comment: Nothing is wrong witht this code. I just want to modify it to load a UIWebView when it sees the closest beacon. The background color change works well.

Comment: like @random suggested, try showing what you've tried and what has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Give the docs a whirl, they are helpful:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString:baseURL:

Comment: thank you. I looked at it and basically just am confused on how to read it. I cant beleive that my instuctors never taugh me this. Any suggestions on how to understand how to use this information as a tool? Sorry for being ignorant. My instuctor loves Wenderlinch, but I dont really care for the learning style. I really need help reading the docs.

Comment: @RobBasso http://www.devfright.com/a-quick-look-at-xcode-documentation-and-how-to-understand-it/ :) Google is your friend!